# Unable to upload large size files using Cordova file transfer plugin

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, cordova

I'm using [Cordova file transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) plugin to upload files to a remote server.I can upload files upto size:28Mb smoothly using my code,but for files greater than this size its returning the following error:

```
FileTransferError {"code":1,
    "source":"file:///storage/emulated/0/test30mb.pdf",
    "target":"http://remoteServer/Upload.aspx",
    "exception":"http://remoteServer/Upload.aspx",
   "http_status":404,...}
```

App's front-end is done in angularjs and ionic framework and backend in .net .

Backend team confirms that no restriction on file-size is done at the backend.

I have already tried:

```
   options.headers : {
                        Connection: "close"
                      }
```

and also:

```
  chunkedMode: false
```

But these didn't help.
Please help me with this.

Comment: try this plugin https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download

Comment: @Naitik - Thanks for the quick response. But I'm having trouble "uploading" large files, not downloading. Also the App is almost done and the above mentioned bug was raised in the final testing. So I guess it would be much more helpful to fix this issue rather than using a different plugin.

Comment: i think it's not issue with upload big size file, it's issue with service call timeout before fully upload file more then **28mb** please try to give service api call time out greater then test and still issue persist please put error logs here